# How do i create a change in font size on hover without realigning other text?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the hover pseudoclass in css to increase the size of individual links in a table, however every time they are hovered over, the size increase affects the size of the rows/columns and all the other links in the table move in accordance.

Any way i can prevent this using only css and html?

Comment: If you think about it, that doesn't really make sense, although if you were make the specific text invisible and position a clone of it over the other, it would probably work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use CSS3 tranform to scale the links without causing re-positioning of surrounding elements, for example:

```
table a:hover{ -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); }
```

`-webkit-` can be changed for other vendors (e.g., `-moz-` and `-ms-`), but is not available in some browsers, including IE8.

Using `line-height` will not prevent horizontal movement, therefore expanding the column.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work applied to span classes.

Comment: @Adrienne `span` elements are not block elements by default. Use `display: block` or a `div`.

Comment: It took me time to understand this answer, so to clarify: you can use `a:hover{ transform: scale(1.2); }`, but some browsers like IE9 should do like this: `a:hover{ -ms-transform: scale(1.2); }`

Answer (score 9):

#### You can do this way:

Set the initial `height` to the `line-height`.

```
td {line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px;}
td:hover {font-size: 20px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mMZjf/

Answer (score 3):

Force the `line-height` height to be the same and change the `font-size` on hover.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/YrbnK/)

Answer (score -3):

You could use relative and absolute positioning:

```
a:link {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: thin solid;
}
a:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6qgd/).